# Node Red: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, undefined, node-red

I'm programming a library to extend the use of sensors and make it more simple for others to use it. My aim is to implement 40 sensors as a node-red-contrib-library in a single node to be published for others to use it simple and intuitive without requiring any further coding regarding the sensors itself.

I'm stuck at a point where I need to use an other library called [node-red-contrib-gpio](https://github.com/monteslu/node-red-contrib-gpio). I thought of either wrap it or adapt it. Sadly I found nothing about wrapping any npm package into an other nor found any help for adapting one. So now I try to ask here for some help.

My current state in adapting the above mentioned npm is as follows:
I managed to recreate the config node as used in the gpio library and register everything but exactly at this point I stuck.

My terminal output looks like this:
[Node Red Terminal error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQx2.png)

```
Welcome to Node-RED
===================

5 Nov 15:49:38 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.16.2
5 Nov 15:49:38 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.10.1
5 Nov 15:49:38 - [info] Darwin 16.6.0 x64 LE
5 Nov 15:49:39 - [info] Loading palette nodes
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn] [wrapper] TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn] [button-eot-v2] TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn] Missing node modules:
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [warn]  - node-red-contrib-eot-sensors: wrapper in, wrapper out, nodebot, wrapper in, wrapper out, node-led, nodebot, johnny5, remote-server
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] Removing modules from config
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] Settings file  : /Users/philipp/.node-red/settings.js
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] User directory : /Users/philipp/.node-red
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] Flows file     : /Users/philipp/.node-red/flows_Philipps-MBP.fritz.box.json
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [debug] loaded flow revision: 62cdd1b04215af983ae9e1a2bac01e43
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [debug] red/runtime/nodes/credentials.load : no user key present
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [debug] red/runtime/nodes/credentials.load : using default key
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] Starting flows
1509893381861 Available Firmata  
1509893381868 Available Firmata  
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [info] Started flows
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [error] [nodebot:Arduino USB-links] Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open /dev/cu.usbmodem1411
5 Nov 15:49:41 - [error] [nodebot:Arduino USB-rechts] Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
```

And to understand the npm a bit more the folder tree:
[Node Red npm folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npdTq.png)

I assume the error occures inside this code of the wrapper.js file

```
module.exports = function(RED) {

    createNodebotNode(RED);

    function wrapperInNode(n) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);
        this.buttonState = -1;
        this.pin = n.pin;
        this.state = n.state;
        this.wrapperbot = RED.nodes.getNode(n.board);
        if (typeof this.wrapperbot === "object") {

            var node = this;
            connectingStatus(node);

            node.wrapperbot.on('ioready', function() {
                var io = node.wrapperbot.io;

                connectedStatus(node);
                if (node.state == "ANALOG") {
                    var samplingInterval = parseInt(n.samplingInterval, 10) || 300;
                    try{io.setSamplingInterval(samplingInterval);}catch(exp){ console.log(exp); }
                    try{io.pinMode(node.pin, io.MODES.ANALOG);}catch(exp){ console.log(exp); }
                    io.analogRead(node.pin, function(data) {
                        var msg = {payload:data, topic:node.pin};
                        node.send(msg);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    try{io.pinMode(node.pin, io.MODES.INPUT);}catch(exp){ console.log(exp); }
                    io.digitalRead(node.pin, function(data) {
                        var msg = {payload:data, topic:node.pin};
                        node.send(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkReady', function(){
                networkReadyStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkError', function(){
                networkErrorStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('ioError', function(err){
                ioErrorStatus(node, err);
            });
        }
        else {
            this.warn("wrapperbot not configured");
        }
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("wrapper in",wrapperInNode);

    function wrapperOutNode(n) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);
        this.buttonState = -1;
        this.pin = n.pin;
        this.state = n.state;
        this.arduino = n.arduino;
        this.wrapperbot = RED.nodes.getNode(n.board);
        this.i2cAddress = parseInt(n.i2cAddress, 10);
        this.i2cRegister = parseInt(n.i2cRegister, 10);
        if (typeof this.wrapperbot === "object") {
            var node = this;
            connectingStatus(node);

            node.wrapperbot.on('ioready', function() {

                connectedStatus(node);

                node.on('input', function(msg) {
                    try{
                        var state = msg.state || node.state;
                        var io = node.wrapperbot.io;
                        if (state === 'OUTPUT') {
                            try{io.pinMode(node.pin, io.MODES[state]);}catch(exp){ console.log(exp); }
                            if ((msg.payload == true)||(msg.payload == 1)||(msg.payload.toString().toLowerCase() === "on")) {
                                io.digitalWrite(node.pin, 1);
                            }
                            if ((msg.payload == false)||(msg.payload == 0)||(msg.payload.toString().toLowerCase() === "off")) {
                                io.digitalWrite(node.pin, 0);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (state === 'PWM') {
                            try{io.pinMode(node.pin, io.MODES[state]);}catch(exp){ console.log(exp); }
                            msg.payload = msg.payload * 1;
                            if ((msg.payload >= 0) && (msg.payload <= 255)) {
                                //console.log(msg.payload, node.pin);
                                io.analogWrite(node.pin, msg.payload);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (state === 'SERVO') {
                            try{io.pinMode(node.pin, io.MODES[state]);}catch(exp){ console.log(exp); }
                            msg.payload = msg.payload * 1;
                            if ((msg.payload >= 0) && (msg.payload <= 180)) {
                                //console.log(msg.payload, node.pin);
                                io.servoWrite(node.pin, msg.payload);
                            }
                        }
                        else if(node.state === 'I2C_READ_REQUEST'){
                            var register = parseInt(msg.i2cRegister, 10) || parseInt(node.i2cRegister, 10);
                            var i2cAddress = parseInt(msg.i2cAddress, 10) || parseInt(node.i2cAddress, 10);
                            var numBytes = parseInt(msg.payload, 10);
                            if(io.i2cReadOnce && i2cAddress && numBytes){
                                if(register){
                                    io.i2cReadOnce(i2cAddress, register, numBytes, function(data){
                                        node.send({
                                            payload: data,
                                            register: register,
                                            i2cAddress: i2cAddress,
                                            numBytes: numBytes
                                        });
                                    });
                                }else{
                                    io.i2cReadOnce(i2cAddress, numBytes, function(data){
                                        node.send({
                                            payload: data,
                                            i2cAddress: i2cAddress,
                                            numBytes: numBytes
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if(node.state === 'I2C_WRITE_REQUEST'){
                            var register = parseInt(msg.i2cRegister, 10) || parseInt(node.i2cRegister, 10);
                            var i2cAddress = parseInt(msg.i2cAddress, 10) || parseInt(node.i2cAddress, 10);
                            if(io.i2cWrite && i2cAddress && msg.payload){
                                if(register){
                                    io.i2cWrite(i2cAddress, register, msg.payload);
                                }else{
                                    io.i2cWrite(i2cAddress, msg.payload);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if(node.state === 'I2C_DELAY'){
                            if(io.i2cConfig){
                                if(register){
                                    io.i2cConfig(parseInt(msg.payload, 10));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(inputExp){
                        node.warn(inputExp);
                    }
                });
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkReady', function(){
                networkReadyStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkError', function(){
                networkErrorStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('ioError', function(err){
                ioErrorStatus(node, err);
            });
        }
        else {
            this.warn("wrapperbot not configured");
        }

    }

    RED.nodes.registerType("wrapper out",wrapperOutNode);


    function nodeLedNode(n) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);
        this.buttonState = -1;
        this.address = Number(n.address);
        this.mode = n.mode;
        this.arduino = n.arduino;
        this.wrapperbot = RED.nodes.getNode(n.board);
        if (typeof this.wrapperbot === "object") {
            var node = this;
            connectingStatus(node);

            node.wrapperbot.on('ioready', function() {
                node.comp =  new NodeLed[node.mode](node.wrapperbot.io, {address: node.address});
                connectedStatus(node);

                node.on('input', function(msg) {
                    try{

                        if(node.mode === 'AlphaNum4' || node.mode === 'SevenSegment'){
                            node.comp.writeText(msg.payload);
                        }
                        else{
                            node.comp.drawBitmap(msg.payload);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(inputExp){
                        node.warn(inputExp);
                    }
                });
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkReady', function(){
                networkReadyStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkError', function(){
                networkErrorStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('ioError', function(err){
                ioErrorStatus(node, err);
            });
        }
        else {
            this.warn("wrapperbot not configured");
        }

    }

    RED.nodes.registerType("wrapper-node-led",nodeLedNode);


    function handleRoute(req, res, handler){
        handler(req.query)
            .then(function(data){
                res.send(data);
            }, function(err){
                console.log('error in wrapper request', err);
                res.send(500);
            });
    }

    function listArduinoPorts(callback) {
        return serialport.list(function(err, ports) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            var devices = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
                if (/usb|acm|com\d+/i.test(ports[i].comName)) {
                    devices.push(ports[i].comName);
                }
            }
            return callback(null, devices);
        });
    }


    function johnny5Node(n) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,n);

        // console.log('initializing johnny5Node', n);
        this.wrapperbot = RED.nodes.getNode(n.board);
        this.func = n.func;
        var node = this;


        if (typeof this.wrapperbot === "object") {
            process.nextTick(function(){
                connectingStatus(node);
            });

            // console.log('launching johnny5Node', n);
            node.wrapperbot.on('ioready', function() {
                // console.log('launching johnny5Node ioready', n);
                connectedStatus(node);

                function sendResults(node,msgs) {
                    var _msgid = (1 + Math.random() * 4294967295).toString(16);
                    if (msgs == null) {
                        return;
                    } else if (!util.isArray(msgs)) {
                        msgs = [msgs];
                    }
                    var msgCount = 0;
                    for (var m=0;m<msgs.length;m++) {
                        if (msgs[m]) {
                            if (util.isArray(msgs[m])) {
                                for (var n=0; n < msgs[m].length; n++) {
                                    msgs[m][n]._msgid = _msgid;
                                    msgCount++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                msgs[m]._msgid = _msgid;
                                msgCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (msgCount>0) {
                        node.send(msgs);
                    }
                }

                var functionText = "var results = null;"+
                    "results = (function(){ "+
                    "var node = {"+
                    "log:__node__.log,"+
                    "error:__node__.error,"+
                    "warn:__node__.warn,"+
                    "on:__node__.on,"+
                    "status:__node__.status,"+
                    "send:function(msgs){ __node__.send(msgs);}"+
                    "};\n"+
                    node.func+"\n"+
                    "})();";

                var sandbox = {
                    console:console,
                    util:util,
                    Buffer:Buffer,
                    __node__: {
                        log: function() {
                            node.log.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            node.error.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        warn: function() {
                            node.warn.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        send: function(msgs) {
                            sendResults(node, msgs);
                        },
                        on: function() {
                            node.on.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        status: function() {
                            node.status.apply(node, arguments);
                        }
                    },
                    context: {
                        set: function () {
                            return node.context().set.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        get: function () {
                            return node.context().get.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        get global() {
                            return node.context().global;
                        },
                        get flow() {
                            return node.context().flow;
                        }
                    },
                    flow: {
                        set: function () {
                            node.context().flow.set.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        get: function () {
                            return node.context().flow.get.apply(node, arguments);
                        }
                    },
                    global: {
                        set: function () {
                            node.context().global.set.apply(node, arguments);
                        },
                        get: function () {
                            return node.context().global.get.apply(node, arguments);
                        }
                    },
                    setTimeout: setTimeout,
                    clearTimeout: clearTimeout,
                    _:_,
                    five: five,
                    board: node.wrapperbot.board,
                    RED: RED,
                    require: require

                };
                var context = vm.createContext(sandbox);


                try {
                    node.script = vm.createScript(functionText);
                    try {
                        var start = Date.now(); //process.hrtime();
                        //context.msg = msg;
                        node.script.runInContext(context);
                        // console.log('ran script', context);

                    } catch(err) {

                        var line = 0;
                        var errorMessage;
                        var stack = err.stack.split(/\r?\n/);
                        if (stack.length > 0) {
                            while (line < stack.length && stack[line].indexOf("ReferenceError") !== 0) {
                                line++;
                            }

                            if (line < stack.length) {
                                errorMessage = stack[line];
                                var m = /:(\d+):(\d+)$/.exec(stack[line+1]);
                                if (m) {
                                    var lineno = Number(m[1])-1;
                                    var cha = m[2];
                                    errorMessage += " (line "+lineno+", col "+cha+")";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!errorMessage) {
                            errorMessage = err.toString();
                        }
                        this.error(errorMessage);
                    }

                } catch(err) {
                    // eg SyntaxError - which v8 doesn't include line number information
                    // so we can't do better than this
                    this.error(err);
                }




            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkReady', function(){
                networkReadyStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('networkError', function(){
                networkErrorStatus(node);
            });
            node.wrapperbot.on('ioError', function(err){
                ioErrorStatus(node, err);
            });
        }
        else {
            this.warn("wrapperbot not configured");
        }

    }

    RED.nodes.registerType("wrapper-johnny5",johnny5Node);


    //routes
    RED.httpAdmin.get("/wrapperserialports", RED.auth.needsPermission("arduino.read"), function(req,res) {
        listArduinoPorts(function (err, ports) {
            res.json(ports);
        });
    });

}
```

And I followed all the documentation found here: https://nodered.org/docs/

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Edit the question to include the actual text NOT images then they can be searched.

Comment: Also you should just pre-req the other node rather than try to wrap it into your package as this will force you to have to keep it up to date

Comment: Thanks @hardillb for you fast answer. I updated the post. But how can I "pre-req" the other npm?

Comment: You include it in your docs that it needs to be installed as well

Comment: Sadly this is not an option though I (my group of students) need to make each sensor into 1 individual node. The gpio connection to the IoT device must be either handwritten or wrapped or required in any way.

Comment: That's very bad design. This is a much larger conversation than Stack Overflow is suited to. I suggest you move this to the Google Group mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, several thoughts.

First, it seems your RED variable is undefined so that is the main problem.

```
createNodebotNode(RED);
```

Then you define a function inside a function:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {

    createNodebotNode(RED);

    function wrapperInNode(n) {
```

And last, you will have a hard time wrapping the whole module just like someone said. Just require the module you need as a dependency, and implement a higher component that will use it. No need to wrap or extend every single function.

Comment: thank you for your help. I right now figured it out! -happy-. Once I finished the node red contrib npm I post a link to the free public npm page here.

Comment: Great! If this answer somehow solved your issue please consider accepting it. If not, please post your solution so others can see how you did it.